# jgrasp. need assistance. cannot figure out how to code this

Tags: java, jgrasp

An email address contains the @ character. Write a program that takes a word from the keyboard and outputs whether it is an email address based on the presence of the @ character. Do not worry about what else is in the word.

Comment: You should show more interest/research in your Q. For instance you should show us what you have tried/code used. As you're a new user please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class EmailAddress 

{
   public static void main(String [] args ) 
   
   {
   
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in );
   
   System.out.print( "Enter your email address here > " );
   int emailAddress = scan.nextInt();

sorry, absolutely new to this. anyways, this is what I have written so far. I keep adding and deleting as when I run it, it doesn't give me what I am looking for. So far, I have coded again and come up with this, but am having trouble pushing forward.

Comment: That's alright. Can you please edit your Q and not post as a comment. Easier for others to read if you put it in your Q.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  public class EmailAddress {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print(" Enter a word: " );
      String word = input.nextLine();
      int count = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if(word.charAt(i) == '@')
          count++;
      }
      if(count > 0) 
        System.out.println("Its an E-mail ");
      else
        System.out.println("Its not an E-mail ");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import  java.util.Scanner;                                //Imports the scanner function

public class TestingCode {                                 //standard java input
 public static void main(String args[]) {                  //standard java input
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in) ;                 //asks the user to input the email they would like to find the domain for
    System.out.print ( "What is the email? : " );
    String email = scan.next();                            //scans for the next string
    int index = email.indexOf('@') ;                       //finds the index at which the @ is located at and stores it as index
    String domain = email.substring (index , email.length() ); //uses the substring function to cut out everything before the @ symbol and stores that snippet as variable domain .
    System.out.print("The email domain is " + domain );     //displays variable domain


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why y'all making this code so complicated?!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*; //I Always import this as a good habit
public class EmailAddress
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" Enter a word: " );
        String word = input.nextLine();
        if(word.contains('@'))
        {
            System.out.println("It's an Email");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("It's not an Email");
        }
    }
}
```